# Changing Field Display Properties

Tags: 7, entities

I'm using Drupal 7, and I have a node type that has an image and body text.  I want the display for this node to display the image inline with the text (ie, apply float:left to the image).

Is there any way for me to do this through the frontend, or will I have to manually change the CSS for the image field's class?

Answer (score 0):

Some themes can do this for you out of the box. See [AdaptiveTheme](http://drupal.org/project/adaptivetheme) as an example -- you can float an image field inline the body field.

I believe with [DisplaySuite](http://drupal.org/project/ds) you can also show fields inline.